# Showing validation error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

Is it possible to show the request validation error message in the error page of my ASP.NET Core app when for instance Identity Server sends a: Requested scope not allowed: {myscope} ?

As it is now, all validation errors just show the /home/error?errorId=12345 page without further information.

So basically my question is: How do I get more details of the validation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to show detailed error messages to the end user - this is a security risk.

Use the log to find out exactly what is wrong.

Comment: So basically whatever error comes from IdSrv4 should never be shown to the user?

Comment: I hooked up our server with Serilog and ApplicationInsights - that gives us all the information we need.
Thanks for pointing the direction and thank you for making this great project!